# CodeIgniter putting html in flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i put some big data like html tags and messages, the session fails, i've tried to use the database but i still get the same error

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '
            <p class="center">Article added successfully</p>
            <p class="center"><a href="/admin/item/add">some other message</a></p>
            ');
```

how to fix this?

Comment: all the session gets destroyed after this action of setting a flash data with big data, i've thinked its using cookies, tried to set the database storing sessions, but i still get destroyed session, why is that? how to fix this? any ideas?

Comment: Fixed, it was just the file encoding Change from ANSI to UTF-8

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the white spaces between tags, like this

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p class="center">Article added successfully</p><p class="center"><a href="/admin/item/add">some other message</a></p>');
```